# Flash drive unable to save data properly?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My flash drive is unable to save data properly. Whenever I save files on my flash drive, 
it shows all data, and when I unplug it and plug it back in, it continues to shows all data (including folders, subfolders, RAR files, etc.) on my system.

However, when I plug the same flash drive into my laptop, it is not able to show all data. It just shows some empty folders, corrupted files, empty subfolders, etc.

Comment: Please tell me you simply don't speak english as a primary language... Anyway what errors? What OS? What Browser (if linux)? Have you tried chkdsk?

Comment: Buddy I m hell worried about my data I have some project in my flash drive thats why and what do you mean by this 'Please tell me you simply don't speak english as a primary language" well I have tried all possible ways to fix my flash drive including chkdsk or etc 
i think you misunderstand my query....
i should ask my question in a simple way so here is my question again ....

Is there any way to repair flash drive ? 
Thanks

Comment: well I use linux windows and window7

Comment: He means your grasp of the English language seems extremely lacking based on your messages with horrible grammar and punctuation. 

More people will be willing to help if you can at least take the effort into typing your question in easy to understand and Correct English.

Comment: I've submitted a suggested edit that should make the question much easier to understand.

Comment: Double check to make sure you don't have more than one partition on the flash drive.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that your flash drives shows incorrectly only on your laptop, is that correct? If so, why do you think the problem is with the flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you tell your OS to "eject" the drive before you remove it.** Because if you remove it without doing that, you can have data on your drive still being written, or in queue for being written, and you will lose that data, or have files get corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important question here since he uses linux and windows is: how is the drive formatted? If it is NTFS linux wont be able to read it, if it is EXT2 or 3 Windows won't be able to read it. Since it is working on one PC and not the other I assume this is the issue. If so on the PC it is working for take everything off the drive and reformat it as FAT32 then put it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Flash drives have a limited lifetime.  After so long and so much use they just wear out.  It might be time to get a new drive... but there could be other issues at foot that answering Lord.Quackstar's questions will help uncover.

Comment: you are right Sir but there are lots of ways to fixed flash drive thats why i m eager to know is there any possible ways to make my flash drive working properly again

Answer (score 0):

Try running `CHKDSK`, preferably with a surface scan (with **Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors** enabled).  This looks like damaged filesystem structures causing problems in reading the contents of the drives, so this may fix the problem.  However, make sure you copy any data that can be read from the drive first.  If this doesn't work, use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to attempt to recover any remaining data, then reformat the flash drive.

**Edit:**  I've realized that you've run `CHKDSK` before, but make sure that you've performed a surface scan.  If there are any bad sectors, replace the flash drive.